# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error in save method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was writing a save method in OrderCompleteStatus model. I want to make , in any order , if the order's OrderCompleteStatus.pickup is True then , for the items of that same order , and for OrderItemCompleteStatus of that item , i want to make OrderItemCompleteStatus.pickup = True.
I have tried but i get RelatedObjectDoesNotExists error in line 458 .
My models are :

```
class OrderCompleteStatus(models.Model):
     order = models.OneToOneField('Order', on_delete=models.SET_NULL , null=True)
     warehouse =models.BooleanField(default=False)
     pickup = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     delivered =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
     received_by_customer =  models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return "Order" + " " + str(self.order)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Order Complete Status'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.warehouse and self.pickup and self.delivered :
        self.order.complete = True
        self.order.save(update_fields=['complete'])
        
    if self.pickup :
        order = self.order
        orderitems = order.orderitem_set.all()
        for item in orderitems:
        (//line 458)item.orderitemcompletestatus.pickup = True
            item.orderitemcompletestatus.save(update_fields=['pickup'])


class OrderItem(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey('Product' , on_delete=models.SET_NULL ,null=True)
     complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     order = models.ForeignKey('Order',on_delete= models.SET_NULL ,null= True)
     quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0 , null=True , blank = False)
     unit_price = models.FloatField(null=True)
     colour= models.CharField(max_length=200 ,null=True , blank=True)
     size= models.CharField(max_length=200 ,null=True , blank=True)
     date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return "OrderItem" + " " + str(self.id)
```

Comment: OrderItemCompleteStatus instead of orderitemcompletestatus is a start, which line is 458?

Comment: @Henty opps sorry , i have edited and added into question , please have a look.

Comment: orderitem_set also needs to be OrderItem_set

Comment: @Henty ooo , ok thanks , will try that